# How can I get this view to my program? (Link in topic)

Tags: android, view

I need to use this view in image. But I don't know, how can I do it.
Unfortunately, I can't add image to my topic, because I'm a beginner on this site, but this image on link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIZ0u.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Android Library [Kankan Wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/).